# Explain the order OR priority of executing the java code?

Tags: java, initialization

I have these two classes

```
public class B {
      int  mB = 5;

    public  int getBValue(){
        return mB;
    }
}

public class A {
     int mA = b.getBValue();

    public static void main(String [] args){
         B b = new B();
        System.out.println(mA);
    }
}
```

The compiler says "can't find symbol b". I understand that code first executing from the main method and line after line in order. So when the compiler reads code it first goes to  "`B b = new B();`" then b becomes defined. Is it true? Is wrong from scope?

Second state that I understand:

```
public class B {
     static int  mB = 5;

    public static int getBValue(){
        return mB;
    }
}

public class A {
     static  int mA = B.getBValue();

    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(mA);
    }
}
```

This state works correctly. Static belong to the class itself, not to any object. So all static loaded and initialized when program run.

So where the key point between these two states?

Comment: `B b = new B();` doesn't create a variable that class `A` can use. It isn't in scope for the class. It's just a "local" variable for the `main` method.

Comment: so we deal with main method like any other method no any privacy for this method ?

Comment: `b` does not have global scope. It is _only_ available to the `main` method, and _only_ until the end of the `main` method . Even if you had some other method that was not the `main` method, and it declared `b` inside of it just like you did in the `main` method, the class `A` would _still_ not be able to access `b`, because `b` is a _local_ variable inside of the method.

Comment: so the compiler read and initialize the declaration of member class first then the method when it's called ?

Comment: That is besides the point. Because the `main` method _created_ the variable, it _only_ exists _inside_ the `main method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128651/discussion-between-android-al-khatib-and-cache-staheli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that code first executing from the main method and line after line in order.

That is entirely correct. However, variables from `main` (or from any other method, for that matter) do not become available for use in field initializers of `class A`, which are executed in their own context as part of class constructor.

> when complier read code goes first to `B b = new B();` then `b` become defined it's true

Yes, `b` becomes defined for the rest of its scope, i.e. up until the closing brace of `main`.

> so where the key point between these two state?

Take-away lesson from this exercise is that field initializers can freely access static fields and methods; they cannot access anything else, including constructor parameters and local variables of any method. Moreover, parameters and locals are off-limits to everything outside their own methods.

Comment: " it has nothing to do with the field initializers of class A"  what do you mean by this , can you give me example?

Comment: @AndroidAL-Khatib `int mA` is a field declaration. `b.getBValue()` expression is its initializer. All initializers are executed in their own context, with no access fields or variables, other than the static ones, which are accessible from everywhere.

Comment: so the compiler read and initialize the declaration of member class first then the method when it's called ? ?

Comment: @AndroidAL-Khatib Member initializers are collected into their own little block of code, which is implicitly attached to class constructor. This code does not get executed until you call a constructor. Static field initializers, on the other hand, are executed before the first method of your class is called.

Comment: it's attached to the constructor but does not belong to the scope of constructor?

Comment: @AndroidAL-Khatib That's correct, initializers do not see local variables from the scope of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Here  :

```
public class A {
     int mA = b.getBValue();

    public static void main(String [] args){
         B b = new B();
        System.out.println(mA);
    }
}
```

`b` is and would be not visible for `A` instance since it is a local variable in `main()` method.  Its scope is limited at the `main`() method.
To be visible, it should be declare as static field in Class A.

Here :

```
public class B {
     static int  mB = 5;

    public static int getBValue(){
        return mB;
    }
}

public class A {
     static  int mA = B.getBValue();

    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(mA);
    }
}
```

It is valid :

```
 static  int mA = B.getBValue();
```

because `B.getBValue()` is accessible in this scope. Anyway, `B.getBValue()` refers to a public static method and by definition, a public static method is accessible everywhere. As it is static, it doesn't need any instance and as it is public, any class may call it.